# Where does the term "Roguelike game" come from?

Tags: terminology, roguelikes

Where does the term "Roguelike game" come from? I've never played this type of game before except perhaps as a coin operated game in an arcade.

Comment: Related: [What attributes makes a game a Roguelike?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/what-attributes-makes-a-game-a-roguelike)

Answer (score 15):

As InvaderSkoodge pointed out in his comment link to the [origin of Rogue-likes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike#Origin)

> The roguelike genre takes its name from Rogue, a role-playing video game based on the Dungeons & Dragons role-playing games, including concepts such as stats and experience points.

Games that follow the *Rogue* trend will often include features such as:

- Randomized Dungeons
- Dungeons and Dragons based leveling
- Unforgiving difficulty (lack of a checkpoint system, perma-death, etc.)

Some good examples of rogue-likes, or games inspired by the roguelike genre, are *FTL: Faster Than Light*, *Crawl*, *Brogue*, *Nethack*, *"Hack, Slash, Loot"*, and, obviously, *Rogue*.

Comment: I'll get flamed for this, but Diablo (1) was a very stripped down roguelike game. Roguelike get a large part of their flexibility because they lack art assets. When I loaded it up the first time, I noted the basic similarities is shared with the rogue-like games I had played on the amiga, atari, pc, cp/m etc.etc

Comment: @horatio I wouldn't say that it's strictly 100% a Rogue-like, but yes, there's definitely some similarities.